# CSS selectors performance of navigation bar and website content

Tags: html, css, performance, css-selectors, tags

I just read some articles about css selectors performance etc. and now I'm confused how to use them in the best way. So I will show you an example of question meaning:

**I'll create a navigation bar on my website and here are some ways how to do that:**

1. Do the tags: **header**, **nav**, **ul**, **li**, **a**
2. Do only div named: **div id="header"** with **ul**, **li** and **a** tags

**CSS styling:**

Depends on which option we want to use, but for the first option, should I style the navigation bar and whole content on the website this?:

```
header {style}
header nav {style}
header nav ul {style}
header nav ul li {style}
header nav ul li a {style}
```

or like this?:

```
header will have class="header"
nav will have class="navigation"
ul will have class="unordered-list"
li will have class="list-item"
a will have class="link"

So it will looks like:
.header {style}
.navigation {style}
.unordered-list {style}
.list-item {style}
.link {style}
```

For the second one option, should I style the navigation bar like this?:

```
#header {}
#header ul {}
#header ul li {}
#header ul li a {}
```

Can someone please tell me which option is better or suggest some other options?

Sorry if something wasn't clear but I'm trying to learn html & css and I'm not really good at english explanation.

Comment: If you're just starting out, my best advice to you is to disregard any performance concerns. Except those who say it doesn't matter. Because it doesn't. Focus on getting the hang of *how* things work, before getting into how *well* or how quickly they work.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use header for semantic. Add **id** if you need it in JS.
2. For stylization use classes. For perfomance it best than tags.

For example

> header nav ul li a {style}

At first, browser search all **a** tags in document. Then it search which of them contains inside of **li** then inside **ul** etc.